# Getting current user after sign in with Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I want to send a verification email after user sign up. I wrote that code but if i want to get the current user with firebase on react native it always return null. How can i fix it?

Here is the sign up function:

```
firebase
.auth()
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(navigation.navigate("WaitingRoom"))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

And also email verification function in `WaitingRoom`:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      user
        .sendEmailVerification()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(":)");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log(":(");
    }
  });
```

I also tried firebase.auth().currentUser but it return null too.

Comment: What do you mean by "it always return null"?? Does it mean that it never happens, in the `onAuthStateChanged`observer that `user`is not null (i.e. you always see the result of `console.log(":(");` in the log)?

Comment: It happens but there is a delay and sometimes i have to reload page. I think i have to wait for response or something like that. But i did not find it. @RenaudTarnec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment above: "It happens but **there is a delay** and sometimes i have to reload page. I think i have to wait for response or something like that."

Yes, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you need to wait that the [`Auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) object has finished initializing.

This is why you should:

- Either use the [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) observer and put the desired code/ business logic in the `if (user) {}` block, where you are sure `user` is not null.
- OR, manually check that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not `null` before triggering the code/ business logic.

---

Concretely, based on what I understand from your question, you could/should call `navigation.navigate("WaitingRoom")` in the `onAuthStateChanged()` observer, as follows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
      user
        .sendEmailVerification()
        .then(() => {
          navigation.navigate("WaitingRoom");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log(":(");
    }
  });
```

Comment: But in my code there is something weird. The console print ":(" but email verification send me a link to verify my email and then it print ":)". Why this code do that?

Comment: This is because the first time the `onAuthStateChanged` observer is triggered the user is `null`, then when all the initialization of the `Auth` object is completed it is triggered **again** (because the user's sign-in state has changed) and **then** user is not `null`.